# XOR Constraint in Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle, constraints

I want to implement a kind of **xor** constraint on foreign keys in mysql 5.1

There is this table, let's say Entity which can refer to two different kinds of valuesets represented by Tables ValsA and ValsB. Now I would like to implement a constraint wich makes sure that exactly one of those two is mapped, and the other one isn't.

In Oracle you could use something like

```
CHECK (NVL2(FK_A,1,0)+NVL2(FK_B,1,0)=1));
```

but as far as I understand it MySQL does not really support CHECK Constraints (yet).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't implement it with more clarity: `CHECK ( (FK_A IS NULL AND FK_B IS NOT NULL) OR (FK_A IS NOT NULL AND FK_B IS NULL) )` ;

Comment: yes you are right. your statement is more readable. but still won't help me. but nevertheless i'll use your suggestion in our oracle application . ty

Comment: As of mysql 8.0.16, check constraints are now possible: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.  MySQL does not support check contraints.  The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

You'd have to enforce the XOR condition on the client side.

Comment: ok thank you. i was hoping there is a fancy alternative way to realize this on db side. my concern is, that a future programmer might oversee this logic if he only touiches the db layer. for example by writing an import script.