# Constrain database to hold one value or the other never both

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

Is it possible to add a database constraint to limit a row to have a single value in one of two columns, never more and never less? Let me illustrate:

```
Sales Order Table
---------------------------------
id  |  person_id  |  company_id |
```

Rows for this would look like:

```
id | person_id | company_id |
---|-----------|------------|
 1 |         1 |       null |
 2 |         2 |       null |
 3 |      null |          1 |
 4 |      null |          2 |
```

In this illustration, the source of the sales order is either a person or a company. It is one or the other, no more or less. My question is: is there a way to constrain the database so that 1) both fields can't be null and 2) both fields can't be not-null? i.e., one has to be null and one has to be not-null...

I know the initial reaction from some may be to combine the two tables (person, company) into one customer table. But, the example I'm giving is just a very simple example. In my application the two fields I'm working with cannot be combined into one.

The DBMS I'm working with is MySQL.

I hope the question makes sense. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: add a trigger that `XOR`s the two columns and fails if violated.

what types of systems are interfacing to create the data?  Can you control the code of those interfaces to `XOR` the data there as well?

Comment: Yes the application will ensure good data integrity. I was hoping for a database-level guarantee as well, though.

Comment: I searched for XOR constraints and I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812468/xor-constraint-in-mysql). According to that answer, it is not possible to enforce XOR constraints on the database-side for MySQL, only on the application-side. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

This may come as a shock...

mysql doesn't support `CHECK`constraints. It allows you to define them, but it totally ignores them.

They are allowed in the syntax only to provide compatibility with other database's syntax.

---

You could use a trigger on update/insert, and use `SIGNAL` to raise an exception.

Comment: MySQL 5.5 introduced the `SIGNAL` statement, which allows you to abort a trigger or stored procedure: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Comment: @bill thanks for the info re signal (it's about time). I'll update the answer.